# Add a time range to query in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, date-range

I have a query that looks into everything put into the database. I need to modify it so that it looks only into what has been changed in a particular time frame, e.g from Julz the first to Julz 31st.

Below you will find the query. If you could tell me how to modify it, I would be glad

```
select
    u.email as writer_email, COUNT(s.id) as numSnips
from
  snippet s
   left join fos_user u on u.id = s.user_id
       group by u.email
       order by numSnips DESC
```

Comment: Do you have in your table a column with the modification timestamp?

Comment: No. How to add it

Comment: Please share the table structure, sample data, and the expected output. Additionally, if your tables do not hold such time information, you should simply add such columns

Answer (score 0):

Without information about the columns in your tables we can not provide a complete solution, but you can just use the `WHERE`keyword (assuming you have a column named `last_changed`):

```
select
    u.email as writer_email, COUNT(s.id) as numSnips
from
  snippet s
   left join fos_user u on u.id = s.user_id
       group by u.email
       order by numSnips DESC
where s.last_changed BETWEEN '2019-10-20 00:00:00' AND '2019-10-20 23:59:59'
```

Of course you have to dynamically generate the dates you need.

Comment: the only two columns present are the writer_email and numSnips

Comment: Then what you want to do is not possible. You first need to create a column and modifiy the software which inserts/edits those records to also save the modification date. SQL doesn't automatically save when you edited or inserted a row.